# Stand alone Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, headless

I'm building a sandbox for testing Android applications and I need to isolate the emulator from the sdk as I wish to reduce the size of the tool as much as possible. I've been searching around for a stand-alone version of the emulator which can be put pre-configured and run without sdk. The important part is that I need adb to work mandatorily.
Where can I find a stand-alone Android emulator (even better if headless) ? Is there any other solution to this ?

Comment: Genymotion is standalone

Comment: As far as I know, the Android Emulator is built into the SDK, and needs it to run. If you want a non-SDK (from Studio) version, use any commercial emulators like Bluestacks

Comment: Can I use Genymotion if I'm publishing it ? Like, it is going to be open for anyone to download. I doubt if their policies hold good for that. @cricket_007

Comment: Genymotion is just an emulator. You install an APK file on it whether or not the app is released.